# GeoPandas gdf.to_postgis: AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'copy_expert'

Tags: python, geopandas, geoalchemy-2

I'm facing the following error with [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/) 0.12.2 when trying to write a very simple GeoDataFrame containing simple points into an existing [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) database:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# stuff...

engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg://user:********@localhost:5432/my_database")
gdf.to_postgis(
    name='my_table',
    con=engine,
)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/script.py", line 56, in <module>
    gdf.to_postgis(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 2052, in to_postgis
    geopandas.io.sql._write_postgis(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/geopandas/io/sql.py", line 461, in _write_postgis
    gdf.to_sql(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2878, in to_sql
    return sql.to_sql(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 767, in to_sql
    return pandas_sql.to_sql(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1918, in to_sql
    total_inserted = sql_engine.insert_records(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1459, in insert_records
    return table.insert(chunksize=chunksize, method=method)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1021, in insert
    num_inserted = exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/geopandas/io/sql.py", line 348, in _psql_insert_copy
    cur.copy_expert(sql=sql, file=s_buf)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'copy_expert'
```

How could I fix that?

##### Version info:

pandas: 2.0.1
geopandas: 0.13.0
sqlalchemy: 2.0.12
psycopg: 3.1.9
geoalchemy2: 0.13.2

Comment: GeoPandas 0.13.0 was released today, and included some fix for compatibility with sqlalchemy 2. Could you check if upgrading geopandas fixes this?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the hint. Indeed, GeoPandas version is now `0.13.0` (I updated the main post) but the error stays exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for testing! Could you open an issue at https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues. That might be easier for further discussion to try to figure out what is going on. This is certainly expected to work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this issue is not so much related to SQLAlchemy 2, but more to the fact that psycopg (version 3) is used, instead of psycopg2. As the psycopg [website describes](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/basic/from_pg2.html#copy-is-no-longer-file-based):

> psycopg2 exposes a few copy methods to interact with PostgreSQL COPY. Their file-based interface doesn’t make it easy to load dynamically-generated data into a database.

> There is now a single copy() method, which is similar to psycopg2 copy_expert() in accepting a free-form COPY command and returns an object to read/write data, block-wise or record-wise. The different usage pattern also enables COPY to be used in async interactions.

In other words, the `copy_expert` method does not exist anymore. So there are 3 ways to solve the problem for now:

1. Wait until [this issue](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/3061) gets resolved by this [pull request](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/3167)
2. Temporarily revert to psycopg2 until this gets resolved in geopandas
3. Install geopandas from the forked git repository that contains the fix. In case you use poetry it would be: `poetry add git+https://github.com/MrAlecJohnson/geopandas.git#enable-psycopg3`